# Scope of @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

For example, I have a code something like this

```
@Transactional(propogation=PROPOGATION.REQUIRED)
public class codeForTest {

  public void doSomethins(){
    User user = userRepository.finduserById(userId);
    updateUserDetails(user);
    updateFewOtherDetails(user);
  }

}

public class DifferentClass{

  @Transactional(propogation=PROPOGATION.REQUIRED)
  updateUserDetails() {
    //UPDATES user object
  }

}
```

I am getting the following in couple of instances with the above logic. I don't get an error in local machine. My question is if updateUserDetails() will commit the transaction and when updateFewOtherDetails() is executed, since the transaction is committed, is it throwing the exception ? I doubt if that is creating the problem since where are annotating it with @Transactional (propogation= PROPOGATION.REQUIRED)

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatch.java:151)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:128)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:482)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
... 130 common frames omitted
 Wrapped by: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:297)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1125.createUserSession(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: In the comments below you note that *By the way, updateUserDetails() is in codeForTest class but it a private method.* which is completely different from the code you have posted. Maybe if you asked a coherent question you might get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JPA (Hibernate) with [optimistic locking](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/). The actual exception:

> org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

means that while your transaction was running another transaction updated the same rows, Hibernate detected their stale state and rolled back current transaction to avoid data consistency problems. This can happen with optimistic locking on a contended resource, but it's not bad because due to rollback the data is still consistent in the database.

There are few ways you can resolve this:

- Retry the logic that caused `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` and hope that next transaction won't be contended.
- Relax transaction boundaries to perform a few smaller and faster transaction
- Queue updates in application logic

Comment: I am very sure that no other thread is doing that. I doubt if updateUserDetails is that other transaction since it has got its own @Transactional and I am sending the that same User object to both the methods. Also, it is a highly consistent error.

Comment: @srinivasvishnu currently your code doesn't even compile. Perhaps if you could provide more complete example one could analyze it better.

Answer (score 0):

Both the methods will be executed in bounds of single transaction, once they both marked `@Transactional`.

`user` object was loaded in bounds of different transaction or taken from cache, in a case `.finduserById()` uses the one.

Make sure you've marked `@Transactional` second `.updateFewOtherDetails()` method too.

With propagation `REQUIRED` the transaction won't commit until the end of caller sequence.

Comment: Do you mean updateUserDetails() ? I already have an @Transactional on updateFewOtherDetails(). By the way, updateUserDetails() is in codeForTest class but it a private method. Will that make a difference ?

Comment: @srinivasvishnu, yes, it will. Since Spring transactions are AOP based, the components are runtime proxies. It means, your methods have to be public and located in different Spring beans in relation to caller. Cross-member calls are not allowed with default configuration.